# Public RPC Rate Limit Hit at Arbitrum node

Tags: blockchain, rpc

I am running at aws an Arbitrum One node. I tried to send multiple transactions (sendRawTransaction) per second but i came up with the error {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":429,"message":"Public RPC Rate Limit Hit, limit will reset in 60 seconds"}}

Had no idea what this is happening, since i run my own node and i cannot find any related flag or config at docs.

Also, i contacted aws support and they inform me that this error is not from their infrastructure.

Can you provide any help/guidance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the public RPC endpoint, switch to a local RPC endpoint instead to avoid hitting the rate limit.

If you're still hitting the rate limit with a local RPC endpoint, try grouping multiple transactions together, increasing the gas price, or reducing the data size of your transactions to optimize your transaction sending strategy.

Alternatively, you can use a dedicated Arbitrum node service like GetBlock instead of managing your own node. This may better suit your needs since dedicated services have higher resource limits and can handle higher transaction volumes.